# compilation errors in sass with 2 instances of @media (max width / min)

Tags: css, sass, compass

When writing the below under just as is, one in-between width media call on top of another in SASS I get a compilation error - error says `'Invalid CSS after "TCY": expected selector, was "@media <max-wid...">` - I don't understand what this means and have used the below in the past; I don't see anything wrong below, any advice?

```
@media (max-width:950px) and (min-width:800px) {
    .clickFacet  {
      width: 93%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 40px;
      max-width: 600px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
}​

@media (max-width:1200px) and (min-width:1000px) {
    .clickFacet  {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: -1%;
      top: 40px;
      max-width: 600px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
}​
```

**Note: //** one will work perfect; if I comment out either one -- they are read, for some reason two isn't liked?

The **error** points me to the start of the second `@media` which ever is below.

Code before per request:

```
body{
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code before it too? I believe the error is telling you where the problem is

Comment: The error points me to the start of the second @media which ever is below.

Comment: Copying your code and pasting it in JSFiddle shows me a red bullet after each closing bracket. Maybe that is the cause of your error? Did you copy this code from somewhere or write it manually? Also I typically do min and max, rather than max and min.

Comment: Can you still post the code before it please? Just so we can see everything that may be causing an issue

Comment: @TylerH  happened the same to me

Comment: @TylerH same here,  once corrected works fine http://sassmeister.com/gist/111d54905272cb9c178f

Comment: @TylerH that was it -- so strange. I don't think it's a terrible answer if you want to write it I'll accept it. Or can just delete the question - but could help others debug, very odd, red bullet.

Comment: @TylerH I posted the answer without seeing your comment, post the answer and I will remove mine. But, yes that was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an error when inserting it into a text editor, it seems that your closing bracket on your first media query was not right, maybe copied code. Anyways, copy, paste this into your css and it should solve the problem.

```
@media (max-width:950px) and (min-width:800px) {
    .clickFacet  {
      width: 93%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 40px;
      max-width: 600px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
}
```